# InterVLAN routing issue

Tags: routing, switch, vlan

I've got one L3 Quanta switch. Having a bit of trouble in understanding the right way to configure VLANs and inter-VLAN routing on it. 
Routing on the switch is enabled.

Ports 0/3 - 0/40 are configured in VLAN 40 and are successfully receiving IP addresses from the IP helper (DNS server).
This is the configuration for them:

```
interface 0/x
switchport allowed vlan add 40
switchport native vlan 40
exit
```

On port 5 I need to set up VLAN 41 which will be used for management on a few other servers. So I've done the following:

```
interface 0/5
switchport access vlan 41
switchport allowed vlan add 41
routing
exit
```

Also, I've set VLAN interface 41:

```
interface vlan 41
ip address 192.168.41.253 255.255.255.0
exit
```

On interface 0/5 I've connected device with static network configuration (to test if it's working) as follows:

```
ip: 192.168.41.100/24
gateway: 192.168.41.253
```

Pinging 192.168.41.253 from the switch obviously works. Pinging 192.168.41.100 doesn't.
Same goes when I try to ping from hosts in VLAN 40.

Apparently I've misconfigured it. I'll be grateful if someone could point me in the right direction.
Let me know if additional info is required.

Comment: Why did you add the routing keyword to interface 0/5?

Comment: It's a leftover from my tries. I've been experimenting a lot in order to get it working.

Comment: Not completely familiar with Quanta, but the process is the same.

Step 1: Verify that the frames on int 0/5 are getting tagged properly for the VLAN. Usually can do `show mac address interface 0/5` and it will show the MAC addresses it sees on that port as well as what VLAN they're tagged for.

Comment: `show mac-addr-table interface 0/5` provides
`VLAN ID 1, status: Learned` 
That's a bit confusing for me..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bit late to answer, but anyway... my issue is resolved in the most bizarre way. I tried all mentioned suggestions, and still couldn't the routing to work.
Finally I left the below config, and on my core switch (the one that the Quanta is uplinked to) I deleted the route, re-added it and things started to flow (?!). Now VLANs 40 & 41 are reaching each other, no matter if I use the Quanta interfaces as gateway, or my core switch.

Anyway, here's my working config right now on port 0/5:

```
interface 0/5
switchport access vlan 41
switchport allowed vlan add 40-41
switchport native vlan 41
exit
```

Comment: You should accept your answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer.

Comment: Oh, sorry. Done.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not familiar with Quanta, but generally, on a L3 switch...

... with regards to interface0/5 from your example:

- either a port is a Layer 3 port [1] (hint: the "routing" keyword), and it needs an ip address and is (internally) attached to some routing instance of the given L3 switch. [2]
- or a port is a layer 2 port, and as such part of one (or more, if 802.1q) VLAN(s) (hint: "switchport access vlan XX"). Then a second L3 interface is needed (for example an *interface vlan XX*) , and must be attached to the same routing instance as the other *interface vlan yy* (or the other Layer 3 port) [2]

in other words:

- either configure interface0/5 as pure routed port and give it the ip
  address you had on *interface vlan 41*, and remove the switchport
  commands from it. Then add *interface vlan 40* with suitable IP
  addressing, and the L3 engine will forward (read: "route") between VLAN40 and
  interface0/5.
- or remove the *routing* keyword (a bit guessing here) from
  interface0/5, and leave the rest, which configures it as switchport in
  vlan 41. The L3 resp. IP part of VLAN 41 is handled by *interface
  vlan 41* just as you already configured it. Then add *interface vlan 40* with
  suitable IP addressing, and the L3 engine will forward between
  *interface vlan 40* and *interface vlan 41* [3].

---

[1] intentionally omitting the case of  802.1q tagged subinterfaces of a layer 3 port.

[2] without further special config, this will be the "default routing table", or "global table", or "default routing instance" or "default VRF" - Names do vary across vendors.

[3] end systems/hosts in VLAN41 and VLAN40 should use their respective addresses of *interface vlan40/41* (or *interface0/5*) as gateways to get to "the other subnet"; in the most simple case in the form of default gateway, or as "next hop" or "gateway address " in additional static routes.